# Canadian couple who died in suspicious circumstances while doing Tibet activism?

Tags: assassinations, citizen-activism, tibet

I seem to remember that about 15-20 years ago a Canadian (?) couple who were both avid Tibetan cause activists were found dead in their home. The wife was found shot to death in their bed and her husband was found on the stairs with a bullet wound in the forehead and the weapon next to him. A manuscript he was working on was found interrupted mid-sentence in his typewriter in his study. The coroner ruled it a murder-suicide, as I recall.

I tried doing a lot of web searches, but they came up dry. A lot of different relevant search terms were tried, but just no luck. I think the activists were authors and had published books about Tibet, but I can't find the names of this couple. Does anybody remember who they were?

Comment: what's this have to do with political processes?

Comment: @dandavis This question falls into the category of "personalities that comprise the political arena".

Comment: @TylerDurden Unless they were major, well-known leaders in that community, there probably isn't a political side to this question.  Just because someone is active within a given cause doesn't automatically make them relevant here.  It doesn't mean they're _not_, but there would need to be some other connection.  If this were considered to be (at one point) an anti-Tibetan hate crime, even if it was later ruled a murder/suicide, then it might be on topic - it'd certainly be easier to find, at least.

Comment: Pretty sure this is referring to Gert Bastian and Petra Kelly - if the question is reopened I'll post a proper answer.

Comment: @CDJB Yes, that's it. Thanks very much. So, I guess they were a German couple, not Canadian.

Comment: @Bobson Does being a founder of the German Green Party count?

Comment: @TylerDurden - Yeah, I'd consider party founders sufficiently political.

Comment: If it was Gert Bastian and Petra Kelly then the deaths happened 30 years ago and don't seem to have an obvious political connection, so maybe this would be a better question for History SE? Though I guess it'd be off-topic there as "too basic" unless their Wikipedia pages are missing something important about their deaths.

Comment: @Giter how does the unexplained murder/suicide of a prominent political couple not have political connection?

Comment: "typewriter": a sign that it was more than 20 years ago.

Comment: @phoog : I think asking about the causes and effects of political figures' deaths would be on-topic here, but just "identify long-dead figures in a half-remembered story" is not.

Comment: @phoog actually, mechanical typewriters are still used in areas with absent or unstable electricity supply. Mostly as backups to PCs/printers, though.

Comment: Were they of Chinese or Tibetan origin? Your story could not have been reprinted by more than 2-3 web papers because it is very specific, and it simply isn't on the web, perhaps a single newspaper cited that they were Free Tibet advocates? China rarely assasinates it's own nationals in the west but never foreign ones from powerful nations AFAIK.

Comment: @Giter that may be true, but that wasn't what you said in the comment to which I was reacting.  You said "the deaths ... don't seem to have an obvious political connection."

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov true.  I don't think any such areas exist in Germany, however, though obviously at the time of writing the question OP obviously had no reason to believe that the incident took place there.

Comment: @LifeInTheTrees they were German.  Tibet wasn't the main focus of their activism, but they were co-authors of a book on Tibet: see for example https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petra_Kelly (search the page for `Tibet`).  Because Tibet was only one of many areas of their concern, most English-language sources covering the incident do not mention it.

Comment: @phoog Weirdly and oincidentally I researched the Free Tibet movement, and found that it probably started in Canada: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/70278/was-ottawa-canada-the-origin-of-the-free-tibet-movement-that-became-world-fam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is referring to [Petra Kelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petra_Kelly), co-founder of the German Green Party, and her domestic partner [Gert Bastian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gert_Bastian) - also a Green Party politician - whose bodies were discovered by police in their home in Bonn in October 1992. The day after, a police announcement stated that no third party was involved and that Bastian had killed Kelly and then himself - according to an [article at the time](https://archive.ph/gAxQq) in The Independent.

The couple had been active in the Tibetan cause; they had edited a book entitled 'The Anguish of Tibet' together, and Kelly received the 2002 Light of Truth Award from the International Campaign for Tibet posthumously.

The circumstances of their deaths also match the details in your question - according to [an article in Der Spiegel](https://www.spiegel.de/politik/der-alte-mann-und-das-maedchen-a-2c6c8c41-0002-0001-0000-000013680052) (in German):

> Very early in the morning of 1 October, Bastian sits down at his
> electric typewriter in the downstairs living room in his shirt and
> trousers and starts writing letters. Nothing unusual about that. The
> old soldier was an early riser.
>
> The addressee of the first letter was not unusual either, with its
> reference to the early hour. It is addressed to his wife Charlotte in
> Munich, whom he had married as a wounded 22-year-old lieutenant in
> Starnberg in Spring 1945. In a familiar conversational tone, he sends
> her his greetings before she leaves on holiday and reports to her with
> satisfaction that Die Zeit has printed his contribution to the
> discussion on the subject of right-wing radicalism. In SPIEGEL it was
> a letter to the editor.
>
> No serious messages, no special concerns - just one of those letters
> with which he keeps in touch with his lively wife and his former life,
> obviously with Petra Kelly's consent. The police find the letter in a
> sealed envelope, unstamped. Plus a second letter, still unfinished,
> addressed to his lawyer in Munich in an irrelevant lawsuit
> (Bastian liked to be right).
>
> The writer of these everyday lines not only stopped in the middle of a
> sentence, but he also stopped in the middle of a word: "must..." The machine is
> still on when the police finally arrive.

The circumstances of the deaths were re-examined by a former Bundeskriminalamt investigator in a 2014 documentary entitled '*Geheimakte Geschichte: Die Mordakte Kelly und Bastian*', which concluded with the same findings as the 1992 police report.

Comment: Regarding Canada, perhaps the entire Free Tibet cause-célèbre originated in Canada due to press reports of the Ottawa demonstrations by tibetans in 1986, where they held placards marked "Free Tibet" and the tibetan flag: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=free+tibet&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3  So what I learned today is that Canada was perhaps the origin of the Free Tibet movement. https://www.google.fr/books/edition/News_Tibet/I2tNi_fqd2wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22free+tibet%22&pg=RA2-PA16&printsec=frontcover

Comment: https://www.latimes.com/archives/la-xpm-1994-11-08-wr-60090-story.html